# Three Tables with same Worksheet

Tags: php, sql

I have three tables with the same work sheet like this

```
[ id  -  title  -  context ]
```

i'm trying to make a relation between them like this

```
$query = "SELECT db.title, db.context FROM table1 db, table2 db, table3 db WHERE id = :id";
```

but i keep getting this error

```
Not unique table/alias: 'db'
```

is there a way to relate between all the tables with same alias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't assign the same alias at diffente table

```
$query = "SELECT db1.title, db1.context 
      FROM table1 db1, 
      table2 db2, 
      table3 db3 WHERE id = :id";
```

but for concatenate the row between the tables,  could be you need  union all  (or union)

```
  SELECT db.title, db.context 
  FROM table1 db
  where db.id = :id
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT db.title, db.context 
  FROM table2 db
  where db.id = :id
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT db.title, db.context 
  FROM table3 db
  where db.id = :id
```